# Location of Main.class in a module definition

Tags: java

I have a small question, given the below:

```
java -p .\dir1 -cp .\dir2 -m a.b/a.b.c.Main
```

It is mentioned that "Main.class should be present in dir1\a.b\a\b\c directory or, if it is inside a jar, then its path should be \a\b\c"

I am struggling to understand how modules work, why is this recommended?
Thank you so much for your help in advance!

Comment: Does this help? http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java/modules.html#:~:text=A%20Java%20module%20is%20a,as%20a%20modular%20JAR%20file.&text=A%20Java%20module%20must%20also,requires%20to%20do%20its%20job.

Comment: Because `a.b.c` is the package. And packages are typically represented by folder structures. Modules did not change that.

Comment: @OldProgrammer thank you so much for the resource. It was helpful in helping me understand how modules work. The main.class should be in the parent directory where module-info file is for it to compile.

Comment: Thank you so much @Slaw, so essentially the directory structure takes the package name format.

Comment: Yes. So if you have a class `com.example.foo.Main` then that class will be in a file located at `com/example/foo/Main.[java|class]`. This is how it's been done since Java was first released (1996), I believe. Modules were added in Java 9 (2017). The `module-info.[java|class]` file is always in the top-level directory of the code (so in the following example it'd be a sibling of the `com` directory). With JAR files being essentially just ZIP files, the "directory structure" is maintained when packaged.